# Is the Olympic Data Feed compatible with the Apache 2.0 License?

Tags: licensing, sports

The Olympics data is available at http://odf.olympictech.org

I want to embed this data in an Android app that I want to release as Open Source.

The "ODF LICENSE AGREEMENT" can be seen on the front page.

The following clause seems to rule out the GNU GPLv3:

> [...] PROVIDED THAT [...] references to the IOC appearing in the Documents [...] are included on ALL such COPIES [...]

Would [Apache 2.0 License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html) be suitable?

Comment: IANAL, but that doesn't seem to rule out GPL to me. I read that sentence only as obliging you to acknowledge the IOC's copyright on the data.